# Drag and Drop between different layout units in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have 4 layout units in full-page Primefaces layout. I have outputlabel in west layout unit. I want to drag it and drop it to center layout-unit. The drop area which I want to drop output label to here is a panel in tabView. When I start the dragging outputLabel don't go out from west layout-unit. Also when I drag it to out of west layout-unit it disappears. How can I solve my problem? I've been working on it for 2 days but I haven't succeed.

**Here is my code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>

        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <p:layout fullPage="true">

                <p:layoutUnit id="top" position="north" header="menu" size="100">
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="bottom" position="south" header="properties" size="100">
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="left" position="west" header="toolbox" size="200" style="overflow: visible" >
                    <p:outputLabel id="out1" value="outputlable"/>
                    <p:draggable for="out1" helper="clone"/>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="middle" position="center" header="sayfa 1" >
                    <p:tabView>
                        <p:tab id="drop_page_1" title="Page 1">
                            <p:panel rendered="#{empty myBean.components}">
                                Please drag any component to here.
                            </p:panel>
                            <p:panel id="tab_panel" rendered="#{not empty myBean.components}">

                            </p:panel>
                        </p:tab>
                        <p:droppable id="drop_page_1" for="page_1"  >
                            <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.f_onCompDrop}" />
                        </p:droppable>
                    </p:tabView>
                </p:layoutUnit>
                <p:droppable for="middle" >
                    <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.f_onCompDrop}" />
                </p:droppable>
            </p:layout>

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

**And here my bean:**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.DragDropEvent;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;


@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class NewJSFManagedBean {

    private List<UIComponent> components;
    public NewJSFManagedBean() {
    }
    public void f_onCompDrop(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {  
        UIComponent comp = ddEvent.getComponent().findComponent(ddEvent.getDragId());
        components.add(comp);  
    }

    public List<UIComponent> getComponents() {
        return components;
    }

    public void setComponents(List<UIComponent> components) {
        this.components = components;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem of dragging items between 2 layout units. I solved it completly via css.

I altered the container where I wanted to drag out of by changing the 'overflow' property to 'visible'.

The second thing I did, was changing the 'z-index' property of the container I wanted to drag into and drop, to a negative value. That fixed it for me.

Comment: finally someone who took the time to explain exactly what he did. I just had the same problem dragging panels from a datalist into a fieldset. Applied your changes and finally the panel stays visible while dragging. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

My issue with drag and drop between primefaces layouts was fixed in the draggable component, by adding appendTo="@(body)" and zindex="5"
Draggable component looks like:

```
<p:draggable for="dragIcon" revert="true" helper="clone" appendTo="@(body)" zindex="5"/>
```