# Primefaces drag and drop image between different <pe:layoutPane />

Tags: jsf, primefaces

We have a datatable with a draggable object.
We are using a two side frame layout, LEFT and CONTENT.
We would like to have those sections resizible, so we tried using p:layoutunit and pe:layoutPane
In both case when we drag the object outside of the CONTENT container into the LEFT one, the image disappear, substituted by a big "plus" sign

How can we maintain the image visible always?
EDIT:
to simplify we create a single page: modify the image with whatever you want, the target is view the image during dragging

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:head>
    <title></title>
    <h:outputStylesheet  library="css" name="style.css"  />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <!--<p:layout>-->

    <pe:layout fullPage="true" >
        <pe:layoutPane position="center" id="center" > 
            <!--<p:layoutUnit position="center" id="center" >-->

            <p:graphicImage value="../resources/images/inMessage.png" >
                <p:draggable revert="true" helper="clone" 
                             />
            </p:graphicImage>

            <!--</p:layoutUnit>--> 
        </pe:layoutPane>            
        <pe:layoutPane position="west" id="west" >           
            <!--<p:layoutUnit position="west" id="west" >-->           


            <p:panel header="Message" style="font-size: 11px;">
                <p:fieldset id="imgDrop" legend="drop here">
                    <p:outputPanel id="dropArea"></p:outputPanel>
                </p:fieldset>
                <p:droppable for="imgDrop"/>
            </p:panel>

            <!--</p:layoutUnit>--> 
        </pe:layoutPane>
    </pe:layout>
    <!--</p:layout>-->


</h:body>    
</html>
```

We have left commented p:layout just to check that the two method have the same behavior

Comment: [mcve] please... is the datatable relevant? The tree? The fact that you use a template? Please simplify but make sure it is a [mcve]

Comment: the draggable object is in a datatable: I'm no sure is "so relevant", but could be. The problem is that I don't know why the icon disappear, and thats the reason I leave the datatable, with just a couple of column

Comment: The tree is the target of the drop, that's why I left it with just one node. The template is there for the same reason: I don't know which part create the problem. Anyway, to receive your suggest, I will try a simplified configuration, just to understand if I can exclude those parts: I'll be back soon with an update, thanks

Comment: @kukeltje: you where right. It not depends by others elements: know you can see a really simply example that reproduce the problem. Any suggest is welcome

Comment: It is not that I was 'right', it could have been that some parts were relevant to the problem. But now your question is 'bare-bones' / almost [mcve], does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32879983/drag-and-drop-of-images-between-layout-units-in-primefaces-layout-is-not-working or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348499/drag-and-drop-between-different-layout-units-in-primefaces contain an answer to your problem?  (found via https://www.google.com/search?q=primefaces+drag+layou)

Comment: It is good to **always** try to create a [mcve]. It strongly increases you chance of directly finding the cause and solving it or finding an  answer/duplicate yourself or getting help. In the last case, it saves us a lot of unnecessary time... Cheers

Comment: what do you mean with " the image disappear"? does the html code get remove from the page or the visibility/display properties of the `img` component get change, if they don't, try adding a high `z-index` to your image, it could be that the image is being place behind your second layout once you move it.

Comment: the solution was add `append_to="@(body)"`, thanks all for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid stacking problem it was necessary to take the draggable object at same level of the panels. So it was solved adding appendTo body 
Thanks to Kukeltje to set me in the right direction

```
<p:draggable revert="true" helper="clone" appendTo="@(body)" />
```

Comment: Thanks, in the text to ;-)